# How to correctly for header paths in Cmake to build Box2D inside my project

Tags: c++, build, cmake, box2d

Trying to build [Box2D](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D). It uses premake as it's build system but I'd like to change it to CMake to compile it alongside my program.

It's main header is `${project_root_folder_here}/Box2D/Box2D.h`. This file includes a bunch of other headers with full paths as well, like `#include "Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h"` and `#include "Box2D/Common/b2Draw.h"`. All Box2D files include corresponding headers via full paths.

My problem is that I don't know how to correctly set CMakeLists.txt to import Box2D sources without changing it's files (`#include` paths) to reflect my project folder structure, which would be the following:

```
project_root_folder
-> Box2D/
---> Common/
-----> ...
---> Collision/
-----> ...
---> Dynamics/
-----> ...
---> Box2D.h
-> MySources/
---> some_header.h
---> some_source.cpp
---> main.cpp
-> CMakeLists.txt
-> Build/
```

I've tried to set `include_directories("Box2D")` and to specify all possible headers and sources, but I am still unable to build it.

Comment: test this simple project in github. it has directory for each module and i think it can be usefull for seprating hearder and cpp file in another directory : https://github.com/panahiehsancom/CMakeTree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<project_root_folder>/CMakeLists.txt`, you could do the following:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This will ensure headers can be found relatively to `<project_root_folder>`